# Notion of a branch in TFS_Warehouse

Tags: tfs, reporting

I'm trying to enhance the following query such that it returns all change sets on a specific branch. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the notion of a branch in the warehouse.

```
   SELECT [ChangesetSK]
         ,[ChangesetTitle]
         ,[LastUpdatedDateTime]
         ,[CheckedInBy__Name]
     FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[vDimChangesetOverlay]
     Where [LastUpdatedDateTime] > '2012-11-26 00:00:00'
```